# Why are Python project files copied after installing requirements in dockerfile and not before?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

Take the sample from https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/ for instance:

```
# ...

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

# ...
```

vs

```
# ...

COPY . .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# ...
```

What are the disadvantages of the latter?

Comment: Caching. In the latter, the requirements are all reinstalled when you change _anything_.

Comment: Your source code files are always liable to change, where as requirements is not that dynamic. So the layer cache will be reused instead of installing again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker [checks every ADD and COPY statement](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache) to see if any files have changed and invalidate the cache for it and **every later** step if it has.

So, in the later, after changes in your code, all `requirements` will be reinstalled.